# Can't access list values by index using ImmutableListMultimap with GWT

Tags: gwt, guava

I am unable to access values by list index when using an ImmutableListMultimap with GWT. I am able to iterate the list of values but trying to access values by index throws an index-out-of-bounds exception. I'm using a ListMultimap to preserve insertion ordering.

```java
ListMultimap<String,String> testMultimap = 
ImmutableListMultimap.<String,String>builder()
      .putAll("key1","value1","value2")
      .putAll("key2","value3","value4")
      .build();

  //this works to get the values correctly, but it's a terrible hack
  List<String> values = testMultimap.get("key1");
  String firstValue = "";
  String secondValue = "";
  int i=0;
  for(String val : values){
    if(i==0){firstValue=val;}
    else {secondValue = val;}
    i++;
  }     

  //throws index out of bound
  firstValue = testMultimap.get("key1").get(0);
```

Partial stack trace:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0
    at java.util.Collections$EmptyList.get(Collections.java:3204)
    at com.google.common.collect.ForwardingImmutableList.get(ForwardingImmutableList.java:46)
    at  com.google.corp.gwt.cell.Cells$3.render(Cells.java:114)
    at com.google.corp.gwt.cell.ForwardingCell.render(ForwardingCell.java:62)
    at com.google.corp.gwt.cell.TableCompositeCell$TableDataCell.render(TableCompositeCell.java:302)
    at com.google.corp.gwt.cell.TableCompositeCell$TableRowCell.render(TableCompositeCell.java:341)
    at com.google.gwt.cell.client.CompositeCell.render(CompositeCell.java:151)
    at com.google.corp.gwt.cell.TableCompositeCell$TableRowCell.render(TableCompositeCell.java:347)
    at com.google.corp.gwt.cell.TableCompositeCell.render(TableCompositeCell.java:91)
        ....
    at com.google.gwt.cell.client.CompositeCell.render(CompositeCell.java:151)  at com.google.corp.gwt.cell.TableCompositeCell.render(TableCompositeCell.java:115)  at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.Column.render(Column.java:165)   at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.AbstractCellTableBuilder.renderCell(AbstractCellTableBuilder.java:206)   at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.DefaultCellTableBuilder.buildRowImpl(DefaultCellTableBuilder.java:129)   at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.AbstractCellTableBuilder.buildRow(AbstractCellTableBuilder.java:87)  at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.AbstractCellTable.buildRowValues(AbstractCellTable.java:2357)    at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.AbstractCellTable.replaceAllChildren(AbstractCellTable.java:2158)    at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.AbstractHasData$View.replaceAllChildren(AbstractHasData.java:245)    at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.HasDataPresenter.resolvePendingState(HasDataPresenter.java:1351)     at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.HasDataPresenter.access$3(HasDataPresenter.java:1062)    at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.HasDataPresenter$2.execute(HasDataPresenter.java:984)    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Task$.executeScheduled$(SchedulerImpl.java:50)     at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.runScheduledTasks(SchedulerImpl.java:180)  at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.flushFinallyCommands(SchedulerImpl.java:278)   at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.exit(Impl.java:296)     at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:287)   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor267.invoke(Unknown Source)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Is the code snippet above enough to reproduce the problem, or is the GWT table shown in the stack trace required?

Comment: If I paste the above into a GWT test and run it, it passes. Let me know if you can reproduce the problem with that code. Maybe we're using different versions of GWT or Guava.